# SweetAlert open another alert with prevent closing previous alert

Tags: javascript, toast, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I want to open another alert along with the previous alert and prevent closing the previous alert, But the previous alert closes and new open.
I used [iziToast](https://izitoast.marcelodolza.com/) and I can do this but I want to use SweetAlert.

**SweetAlert Example:**

```js
const swalToast = Swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  iconColor: "white",
  customClass: { popup: "colored-toast" },
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timerProgressBar: true,
});

swalToast.fire({
  title: "One",
  position: "bottom",
  timer: 5000,
  icon: "info",
});

setTimeout(() => {
  swalToast.fire({
    title: "Two",
    position: "bottom",
    timer: 1500,
    icon: "info",
  });
}, 2000);
```

[image]

**iziToast Example:**

```js
iziToast.info({
  position: "bottomCenter",
  title: "One",
  message: "",
  timeout: 5000,
});

setTimeout(() => {
  iziToast.info({
    position: "bottomCenter",
    title: "Two",
    message: "",
    timeout: 1500,
  });
}, 2000);
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe if you do the first alert in modal box and the second one is the alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to show more than one modal at a time, by design.

[SweetAlert open another alert with prevent closing previous alert](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/2387)

[Show two swal at same time](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/606)

[2 or more modals at the same time](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/770)